# Copying a block of 182,000 files, after 48,000 or so it comes to a crawl .. is this right?

Tags: 16.04, hard-drive, ntfs, external-hdd

I'm using Beyond Compare to copy large blocks of files from my internal HD to a Seagate Backup Plus 4Tb external drive in NTFS format.
My blocks are typically around 200,000 files of test vectors.
After about 20% has copied, it comes to a crawl .. seeming to stop at times.
Sometimes a gentle "sync;sync;sync" gets it moving.
One one occasion, it really got gummed up .. was hard to shutdown even.
Left the /media/user/HDrive mount point ... which made it hard to remount.

What am I doing wrong or right ?  How do I avoid the crawl moments ?

I don't see this problem with a WD Passport 4Tb external HDD

Comment: Are you attempting to copy too many files into a single directory?  NTFS can in theory handle 4 billion files per directory, but in practice it becomes a little slow.

Comment: no more that 350,000 files in any directory.

Comment: Had this happen this morning.  It was taking 35 minutes to copy a 9Mb file.  Finally, tried to eject and it claimed a 'pending command' or such.   Have it on Windows now running a chksdk /f

Comment: Just for fun, try to limit it to 50k files per directory